# use for each value in jsp tag

Tags: java, jsp, foreach

I have a foreach value in an iteration in a jsp page as shown

```
<c:forEach var="lists" items="${lists}" varStatus="theCount">

String val=   ${lists.getVal() } ; //this is giving me error


</c:forEach>
```

Comment: What is this meant to be `String val=   ${lists.getVal() } ; //this is giving me error`. What exactly is it you want to do?

Comment: to assign this value lists.getVal() to string that is what i am trying out

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${lists}" varStatus="theCount">
   <c:set var="val" value="${list.val}"/>
   <p>The value is: ${val}.</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I want to assign it to a string on the jsp page

Comment: I think maybe you need to go and read up on some fundamentals.

Comment: This line is incorrect `<c:set var="val" value="list.val"/>`
It needs to be `<c:set var="val" value="${list.val}"/>`

Comment: Because otherwise what you will see is this `The value is: list.val` in your `<p>` tag

Comment: Yes, of couse. Updated.